# Checkbox will not fire function onLoad of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've been banging my head on this issue for 8 hours straight and I can't figure it out.

**Environment**:  I'm developing a webapp which has a button/switch that toggles a checkbox when clicked/checked. When the checkbox is checked, it fires a function that calls a PHP script.  When UNchecked, it pauses the PHP script. This is all working great.

**ISSUE**: I also have the checkbox configured to be in a checked state when the page loads, thus triggering the function automatically when the page loads. 
 However, right now, when I load the page the checkbox IS checked, but the function DOES not fire automatically UNTIL the checkbox is toggled manually.

I've used A LOT of different variables and solutions, but I can't figure it out.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the "Label" class?

What am I doing wrong?

**Example**:
You can ignore the PHP stuff, as I put in an alert for testing. YOu'll the checkbox is checked onload, but the alert does not fire onload but will fire when the checkbox is manually checked.

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seanvree/vx67mLjd/)**

```
<script>
  var nIntervId;
  var onload;

  function statusCheck() {

    $("#statusloop").load('assets/php/loop.php');
    $("#stats").load('assets/php/systembadges.php');

  };

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        nIntervId = setInterval(statusCheck, 3000);
        alert("checked");
      } else {
        clearInterval(nIntervId);
        alert("NOTchecked");
      }
    });
  });

</script>

<body onload="statusCheck()">

  <label class="switch" id="buttonStart">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>

  <script>
    $('#buttonStart :checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You haven't the html entities of #statusloop and #stats. jQuery failing silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, there are two things you have to do:

1. Check the checkbox after setting the `change` event. In your code, you check your checkbox before setting the `change` event.
2. You must trigger the `change` event manually, because, making changes through `JavaScript` to an `input` does not trigger the `change` event. You can do this by calling `change()`, if you've already set the event or `trigger("change")` to trigger the `change` event in general.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Set the 'change' event. */
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    // ...
  });

  /* Check the checkbox and trigger the event. */
  $('#buttonStart :checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked').change();

  // OR → $('#buttonStart :checkbox').trigger("change");
});
```

Check out an updated version of your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vx67mLjd/12/) or the following snippet.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var nIntervId;
var onload;

function statusCheck() {
  $("#statusloop").load('assets/php/loop.php');
  $("#stats").load('assets/php/systembadges.php');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Set the 'change' event. */
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      nIntervId = setInterval(statusCheck, 3000);
      console.log("checked");
    } else {
      clearInterval(nIntervId);
      console.log("NOT checked");
    }
  });

  /* Check the checkbox and trigger the event. */
  $('#buttonStart :checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked').change();
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch" id="buttonStart">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

---

**Reference:**

[Here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/should-chk-prop-checked-true-trigger-change-event) is a topic from the forums of `jQuery` highlighting this specific issue.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @SeanVreeland. Have a nice day 

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your **ready** function and it will work.

```
  if ($(':checkbox').is('checked')) {
    //    dosomething() ;
    alert('checked');
   } else {
      alert('not cheked');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling a PHP-script using WebSockets would probably be a better approach.

That being said, you can fix your script by triggering the interval in `document.ready` and doing the `is(':checked')` inside the `statusCheck` function. This way the interval is always running and the load is executed only if the checkbox is checked.